# Which tree produces heart shaped seeds enveloped in a long pod?

Tags: united-states, trees, tree-identification

Which tree native to Florida produces these seeds? The pods are really long and the seeds inside are in the shape of little hearts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you know the tree is native and not invasive? There are pods which come ashore. Here are some [giant versions](https://www2.palomar.edu/users/warmstrong/plmay97.htm).

Comment: Perhaps, but it came from a tree that was growing in Florida. It’s not any of those BTW

Answer (score 4):

With pictures posted, it looks like it is the African tulip tree ([Spathodea campanulata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathodea)). The decisive features were the long pod with the pores. Similar (but not as strongly heart-shaped) seeds are seen in the [jacaranda tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacaranda), which has a wider and rounder pod, which usually opens with an outer membrane attached to the edges.

Comment: That’s not it, I wish there was a way to post the picture that I took.

Comment: There should be - hid "edit" and under the menu bar that pops up there will be a symbol that looks like a mountain landscape - that's the "add picture" button.

Comment: You may need more than 1 rep to see that post picture option. But everybody can post the photo online like in imgur, and post the link in their question (or answer.)

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh  Identification added as an edit.

Answer (score -1):

[image: enter image description (https://i.stack.imgur.com/59vE9.jpg)![enter image description here]

It is from the Mugumo tree. I took this pic in Nairobi Kenya.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you have the wrong trees' seeds there - the Mugomo tree is from Kikuyu culture, and is a [Fig species (_Ficus sycomorus_)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_sycomorus), which all have globular fruit, not winged fruits like [samara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samara_(fruit)).